# How to get song from relative or absolute path in react without importing File

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

import Song1 from './Songs/Tum Mile.mp3';

const Player123 = () => {
let location = useLocation();
const soundUrl = location.state.src;
useEffect(() => {
console.log(soundUrl);
}, soundUrl);
return (

<div>
  <audio src="/Users/rajatgarg/Desktop/Project/Muser/front-end/src/Components/Songs/Tu Tu Hai Wahi.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
);
}
export default Player123;
```

I can't add the song to the HTML file in react if I use soundUrl(relative URL) and not even by absolute URL. If I import Song1, I can access the song in the HTML file by using <audio src={Song1} controls></audio>. Please tell a way by which I can access the song without importing it and just by using the path that I sent through the parameter.

Comment: The path needs to be a) relative to web root, and b) to something your react build will include in its output.   You're currently showing a full OS-level path; that will definitely not work.  For react you probably want https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/